# Is it possible to align a span to left when hovering a div which is not the parent?

Tags: html, css, hover, transform

I tried aligning my span to the right when i hover a div, which is not a parent of the span. Is this possible?? i have a section in which there are 6 divs and 6 spans.

```
<section  id="section1">
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div1"></div>
    <span></span>
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div2"></div>
    <span></span>
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div3"></div>
    <span></span>
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div4"></div>
    <span></span>
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div5"></div>
    <span></span>
    <div class="aboutusdiv" id="div6"></div>
    <span></span>
</section>
```

```
#section1 span {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

#section1 div:hover span {
  transform: translate(60%);  
  width: 500px; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible if there's no sibling-type relation between the elements. It because the CSS is `cascading`

Comment: Can you drop your HTML on here too please?

Comment: Is there any possible to align a div to right and this span to left. without the relationship... bczz i want all the divs in center and i used grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. In my example I'm using the `+` operator in the selector and you can test it by hovering on **a**.

```css
#section1 span {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

#section1 span:hover + span {
  transform: translate(60%);  
  width: 500px; 
  color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
</div>
```